# ReactAdmin sticky the RichTextInput toolbar to the top of the text field even when scrolling the page

Tags: css, react-admin, tiptap

How can I sticky the RichTextInput toolbar (I thin the CSS class is RaRichTextInputToolbar-root) on the top of the rich text field?
I tried but only made to use position: fixed and it fix it relative on the viewport, not the field and make the toolbar get fixed on the top of other fields in some cases.
I tried  position: sticky but it not work (the toolbar works as default).

Even if I create a custom component, I don't know how to make it work this way.
Maybe the bubble extension for tiptap (https://tiptap.dev/api/extensions/bubble-menu) would work, but I don't know how to implement it in react-admin and if I can use it with more then bold/italic/strike like their example.

I have a component for it, changed, but don't know how to fix the toolbar (I have some CSS, but it not work with sticky and with fixed make the toolbar above other items when on the top) or the bubble

```
import {
    RichTextInput,
    RichTextInputToolbar,
    LevelSelect,
    FormatButtons,
    ListButtons,
    LinkButtons,
    // QuoteButtons,
    ClearButtons,
} from 'ra-input-rich-text';

export const RichTextSmallToolbar = ({ size, ...props }) => (
    <RichTextInput
        toolbar={
            <RichTextInputToolbar>                
                <FormatButtons size={size} />
                <ListButtons size={size} />
                <LinkButtons size={size} />                
                <ClearButtons size={size} />
                <LevelSelect size={size} />
                {/* <QuoteButtons size={size} /> */}
            </RichTextInputToolbar>
        }
        label="Body"
        source="body"
        {...props}
    />
);

.RaRichTextInputToolbar-root {
    overflow: initial;
    position: sticky !important;
    padding: 5px 5px 0px 5px;
    top: 50px;
    z-index: 2;
    background-color: #1e1e1e;
    border-radius: 5px;
}
```

Anyone already did it? Could help me with some code?

Thanks in advance!